# how to fit layout to screen without space left and right corners in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In my layout i am getting space left margin and right margin but i need fit to screen i don't need left and right margin in some layout here below my code any one please help me

XML
I need two layout fit to screen without any space in left margin and right margin to my last two layouts any one please help me how to get this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/un_named"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageview_text"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/un_named"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv01"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Moviewheewd  ewudwd wedewd w"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv02"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=" wjh wd wed we dtext"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv03"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="simple   text"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv04"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="simple  jwehd wj dewjd"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv07"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="simple  heds  xaks katext"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btun1"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butn2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/down"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#FFFFFF">
         <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textreview_dec"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="fs dsfjsdf sjf ds fds fsd fds fds  fs fmdmsn fsm fsm fsm fdsm f
              hdfbsd fsdjfhsd dfdsj fsd fdsj fds fds fdsj fsd df
              fsdfhsd dfjsd fhds fjs fds fjds dfs
              dskjfsd fsd fs dfsd dfsd fs dfksd fkds fkds fdks fdsk fdsk f
              f skdf sk fksd fksd fdsk fsk f f  ff df
              f skf skf ksdf  fsk fkdfdkdf ksf
              fks fsk dk fks fdks fdksf sk f
              f skdf skf ksf skdf dsf df dskf kdf kds
              f ksd fdksf dskf df dskf dskf dsk f dsk f
              fksf s fksd "/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="183dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/imginews"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            /></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` from root `LinearLayout`

Comment: but in my first layout i need space left and light

Comment: Then add padding to the first layout only.

Comment: widget(TextView,ImageView)  remove padding    android:paddingLeft="10dp"

Comment: i put their but space not getting@camelCaseCoder

Answer (score 0):

Your answer - Last 2 LinearLayouts without any left and right padding.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/un_named"
android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_text"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/un_named"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv01"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Moviewheewd  ewudwd wedewd w"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv02"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text=" wjh wd wed we dtext"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv03"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple   text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv04"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple  jwehd wj dewjd"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv07"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple  heds  xaks katext"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btun1"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butn2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/down"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#FFFFFF">
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textreview_dec"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="fs dsfjsdf sjf ds fds fsd fds fds  fs fmdmsn fsm fsm fsm fdsm f
          hdfbsd fsdjfhsd dfdsj fsd fdsj fds fds fdsj fsd df
          fsdfhsd dfjsd fhds fjs fds fjds dfs
          dskjfsd fsd fs dfsd dfsd fs dfksd fkds fkds fdks fdsk fdsk f
          f skdf sk fksd fksd fdsk fsk f f  ff df
          f skf skf ksdf  fsk fkdfdkdf ksf
          fks fsk dk fks fdks fdksf sk f
          f skdf skf ksf skdf dsf df dskf kdf kds
          f ksd fdksf dskf df dskf dskf dsk f dsk f
          fksf s fksd "/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/imginews"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: firstLayout not getting space left and Right@Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_text"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Moviewheewd  ewudwd wedewd w"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text=" wjh wd wed we dtext" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple   text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple  jwehd wj dewjd
        " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv07"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="simple  heds  xaks katext" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btun1"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butn2"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/cast_ic_notification_1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textreview_dec"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fs dsfjsdf sjf ds fds fsd fds fds  fs fmdmsn fsm fsm fsm fdsm f
          hdfbsd fsdjfhsd dfdsj fsd fdsj fds fds fdsj fsd df
          f ksd fdksf dskf df dskf dskf dsk f dsk f
          fksf s fksd " />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Video"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this code and replace your images again.
I hope this will help you.